# BLE connection using python on windows 11

Tags: python, bluetooth

I am trying to make a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) connection using python 3.7 and a computer with windows 11. I found a code for searching the device and make the connection. The first part (search device) seems to be working, however the second one gets stuck (connect to device).
Here you have the code:

```
#FIND DEVICE

import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner
from bleak import BleakClient
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


async def run():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())


# CONNECT TO DEVICE gets stack!!

adress  = "CF:34:4E:3D:D9:64"

async def main(address):
    print("Connecting to device...")
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        print("Connected")
        cs = 1

asyncio.run(main(adress))
```

This is the code part that seems to get stuck: `with BleakClient(address) as client:`
I have tried using different libraries like `pexpect` but seem to be working just for Linux...
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Which version of Bleak are you using? Have you paired the PC and the BLE device? For reference: https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/issues/688

Comment: I manage to find the problem... it seems that BLE is not working properly with windows 11. I change to windows 10 and worked!